# SkinnablePopUpContainer error

Tags: actionscript, air, popup

I have used this approach before and always worked but today I seem to be having a major problem with displaying a SkinnablePopUpContainer:

I have a SkinnablePopUpContainer in a MXML file. (mobile app, fb 4.6, air 3.4)

I create and display the popup this way:

```
public var su:setupdialog;


private function Showdialog():void{
                su = null;
                su = new setupdialog();
                su.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE,SetupClose);
                su.open(this,true);
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(su);

        }
```

I have also tried the following:

```
private function Showdialog():void{
                su = null;
                su = new setupdialog();
                su.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE,SetupClose);
                PopUpManager.addPopUp(su, this, true);
                su.open(this,true);
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(su);

        }
```

The problem seems to be with the "this" global variable.
I keep getting the :

"ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller."

I'm at a losses because I have done this before and all worked.

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right `this` should be DisplayObjectContainer like any container like Group, VGroup class.

Second function won't work SkinnablePopUpContainer.open() internally add your popup window so proably it not need.

It works for me.

```
private function Showdialog():void
{
    su = null;
    su = new setupdialog();
    su.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE,SetupClose);
    su.open(this,true);
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(su);
}
```

Comment: Also I found out that I did not have a default view set for the states in the popup...